# How to query the items of a nested json/dict

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

My table is contacts_contact while the column is called fields.

Just for context, the first part of the json I'm interested in represents a flow ID and the corresponding response from the user.

Like this: `<Key, which is the flow id>:{"text", "false"}`

Where text is the data type of my field and false means that the user did not consent. They could also choose true and consent.

In pseudo code, here's what I'm trying to do:

1. Search through contacts_contact
2. Return all rows where the key is `6784cbd4-505d-4ee4-8568-fb69913d6998` 
   **AND** the reply (value) is false. (meaning that 'text' is 'false')

In other words, every row that has `"6784cbd4-505d-4ee4-8568-fb69913d6998": {"text": "false"}` in the fields column should be SELECTED.

Here's a sample data under the fields column. The first part is what I'm interested in retrieving.

```
{
  "6784cbd4-505d-4ee4-8568-fb69913d6998": {"text": "false"},
  "70454b00-f408-4e69-8013-b010c3130fdd": {"text": "2020-05-04",
  "datetime": "2020-05-04T09:38:42.329388+02:00"},
  "9fc9e443-4bbb-4356-b9cc-71a6c15ded0e": {"text": "<1 month"},
  "abb3bb06-d4b7-4a58-8a3f-b100074b20a2": {"text": "<1 month"},
  "b55eb0e6-af0d-48c7-b2eb-f46529bdd07b": {"text": "True"},
  "b692354b-f314-406a-8ed8-47b7dde34379": {"text": "true"},
  "c7d75b60-f1d8-4588-affa-4ef148c75873": {"text": "WhatsApp"},
  "c80e14a9-e10f-41c8-ae59-c0ca14abf806": {"text": "true"},
  "cbfd64b8-739c-4913-b8c9-ba366043f1bd": {"text":
  "2020-04-20T00:00:00.000000+02:00", "datetime":
  "2020-04-20T00:00:00.000000+02:00"},
  "d5423a09-5486-4b80-bcae-4fc1e11b0dfa": {"text": "true"},
  "db36481d-3bb2-435d-b63d-bc9d5b5eadd3": {"text": "TRUE"},
  "e0f301ab-56eb-4bba-a6c1-d9668033172f": {"text": "Late Adopter"}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using the contains operator `@>`

```
select *
from contacts_contact
where fields @> '{"6784cbd4-505d-4ee4-8568-fb69913d6998" : {"text": "false"}}';
```

The above assumes that `fields` is a `jsonb` column (which it should be). If it's not, you need to cast it: `fields::jsonb`